# Order of object is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to bind dynamic data , after I bind the data the order of data is getting changed

```js
var app = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.fieldNames = { author_name: "Author Name", about_author: "About author", author_image : "Author Image" };
    $scope.authors = [{author_name: 'akshay', about_author:'this is about author', author_image:'image url here'}];
  console.log($scope.authors);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

    <div ng-repeat="author in authors" class="authorAndTagGroup">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in author">
        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">{{fieldNames[key]}}</label> 
        <input type="text" ng-model="author[key]">
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to display like

Author Name : akshay

About author : this is about author

author_image : image url here

Comment: There is never an order guaranteed with `for..in` loops. Hence when you are doing the inner `ng-repeat` you  are missing the order. 

You could explicitly bind the values in the order you want.

Comment: It seems to me that data is already displayed in your expected order. [See plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YdJzOtvqXEZsVp66zAoG?p=preview)

Comment: @KhalidHussain pls run the snippet it's not working properly

Comment: @Jimbrooism yes, in your code snippet it's not working, [but it is working in my plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/YdJzOtvqXEZsVp66zAoG?p=preview).

Comment: @KhalidHussain I am found the problem, the snippet is running on angular 1.2.23 and the plnkr is in 1.5.3, if u change 1.5.3 to 1.2.23 it will not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the problem will be solved if you use higher version where this issue been resolved(e.g-> `1.5.3`).

[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/YdJzOtvqXEZsVp66zAoG?p=preview)

I suggest you to have a look at the migration doc. It will help you to avoid future problems.

[From migration doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#templating-ngrepeat-compile-):

> Due to [c260e738](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c260e7386391877625eda086480de73e8a0ba921), previously, the order of items when using ngRepeat to
>   iterate over object properties was guaranteed to be consistent by
>   sorting the keys into alphabetic order.
>
> Now, the order of the items is browser dependent based on the order
>   returned from iterating over the object using the `for key in obj`
>   syntax.
>
> It seems that browsers generally follow the strategy of providing keys
>   in the order in which they were defined, although there are exceptions
>   when keys are deleted and reinstated. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Cross-browser_issues
>
> The best approach is to convert Objects into Arrays by a filter such
>   as https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter or some
>   other mechanism, and then sort them manually in the order you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should always explicitly define your property names, as ordering in for each (like ng-repeat) loops is never guaranteed.

So i would recommend a single loop (instead of a nested loop), as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="author in authors" class="authorAndTagGroup">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Author Name</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="author_name">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">About Author</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="about_author">
    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Author Image</label> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="author_image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem got solved when i am changed my angular version 1.2.23 to 1.5.3